# TypeError: b is not a function error in React.js with redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am working with react application with redux-saga. It gives below run time  error.

```
b is not a function
TypeError: b is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58975:48
    at ./src/redux/store.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1029:189)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59638:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59031:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59295:21)
    at ./src/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:636:74)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59638:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59031:33)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60284:37
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60286:12
```

this says error in `store.js`

Below i have attached my `Store.js` code

```
import {compose,applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers/index'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import rootSaga from './sagas';
import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from 'redux';

const sagaMiddleware=createSagaMiddleware();
const store=compose(
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
    window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension(),
)(createStore)(rootReducer)

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

also it mentioned about index.js therefore i have check both store.js and index.js files. But i couldn't find the error. below i have attached my index.js code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
// import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from '../src/redux/reducers/index';
import store from '../src/redux/store';


const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

if (!rootElement) {
  throw new Error("Root element with id 'root' not found in the document.");
}

ReactDOM.render(

  <Provider store={store}>
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I am beginner to redux-saga. can you help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are creating the store looks a bit odd. If I am reading your code correctly you are composing the middlewares, ***then*** trying to invoke its returned function and pass the `createStore` function to it... and later still invoke *that* call's return value and pass your root reducer function.

You should be calling `createStore` and passing the root reducer and middlewares as arguments. Try the following rewrite.

```js
import {
  legacy_createStore as createStore,
  compose,
  applyMiddleware
} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  undefined, // <-- initial state, any preloaded state would go here
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
    window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension(),
  ),
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

Note that you are using outdated Redux. Modern Redux is written using [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/). It's much less boiler-platey and more succinct.

Example:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(sagaMiddleware),
});

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```